# How can I write to external HDFS in another ubuntu?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ubuntu-16.04

I have two ubuntu machines.
Let's say A(10.10.1.1) and B(10.10.1.2).

Using machine A, I want to write into HDFS of machine B. **(A -> B)**

### What I've already tried

**On machine A**, I typed

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir hdfs://10.10.1.2:9000/user/zz
```

which led to error
`mkdir: Call From MYNAME/10.10.1.1 to 10.10.1.2:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused`

**On machine A**, I already typed

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir hdfs://10.10.1.2:50010/user/zz
```

which led to error
`mkdir: End of File Exception between local host is: "MYNAME/10.10.1.1"; destination host is: "10.10.1.2":50010; : java.io.EOFException; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EOFException`

### My configuration

**core-site.xml in machine B**

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
                <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                 <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
                 <value>/data</value>
         </property>
</configuration>
```

**core-site.xml in machine A**

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
                <value>hdfs://10.10.1.2:9000</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

I'm really waiting for your answers.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hadoop doesn't quite work like that...you store files to the file system, the underlying implementation decides where exactly the files end up.

Comment: Did you define your `hdfs-site.xml` files?

Comment: @tk421 Yeap. I set `dfs.replication=1`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by revising /etc/hosts file.
As [ConnectionRefused Error](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/ConnectionRefused) says, Ubuntu is notorious for mapping hostname to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Could you please specify what did you exactly revise? I have the similar problem on Mac OS